# improving the efficiency of simple function

Tags: ocaml

This is the signature of my "transform" method:

```
let rec transform (f: -> 'a -> 'b) (l: 'a list): 'b list =
begin match l with
| [] -> []
| hd :: rest -> (f hd) :: (transform f rest)
end
```

The idea is that I want to find the complement of a nucleotide. G is complementary to C and A is complementary to T.

This is how I implemented my function, but I was wondering if there is possibly a more efficient way of doing this than a bunch of nested if statements.

```
type nucleotide = G | C | A | T
type helix = nucleotide list

let complementary_helix_f: nucleotide -> nucleotide =
fun (n: nucleotide) -> if n = G then C
                       else if n = C then G
                       else if n = A then T
                       else A
```

Comment: As an aside, your `transform` function is usually called `map`, and is part of the standard library.

Comment: It is called `List.map`, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml generates good code for `match`, so you might try the following:

```
let complementary_helix_f = function
| G -> C
| C -> G
| A -> T
| T -> A
```

It's also (maybe) a little easier to read.

If you really need to worry about speed, you should profile your code (after you get the whole thing working).